# Moving existing cacti to apache2 root folder

Tags: apache2, cacti

I have a running cacti installation on /var/www/html/cacti where is cacti installs by default on ubuntu 14.04lts. I would like to move cacti to apache's root folder at /var/www/html/ without disrupting anything. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Just edit the path at /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
Change DocumentRoot to the path of cacti; mine was /usr/share/cacti/site
service apache2 restart